# Wordpress Navigation Menu Image

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation

I am just starting to learn some CSS and have been able to customize a free theme on Wordpress a lot, but I am completely stuck on getting a custom image behind my navigation menu text. The theme I am using is Retrotale and have not heard anything from the author or other forums.

I had the same menu on an old theme and the CSS showed it was using a Genesis theme.  The image is http://caffeinatedandcreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Navtrial.png  I have tried looking for the correct coding to suit my new theme as the old code doesn't seem to work because I am not sure if the new theme is a Genesis theme and I am not sure where to make changes.

I have tried adding it in random places in the editor and also used the custom CSS plugin. For some reason,  when I use custom CSS plugins, any CSS I enter never seems to work, yet when editing it directly editing the theme editor, changes are made.

```css
.genesis-nav-menu {
 clear: both;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
 letter-spacing: 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 5;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0px 0 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
border: 0px solid #000;

border: radius 10px;
 background: url('http://caffeinatedandcreative.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Navtrial.png');
 background-size: 1200px 100px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 max-width: 1000px;


}
#container,
#container-title,
.top-navigation {  
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 

.genesis-nav-menu {
 clear: both;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
 letter-spacing: 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 5;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0px 0 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
border: 0px solid #000;

border: radius 10px;
 t 
 background-size: 1200px 100px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 max-width: 1000px;

}
```

Thank you!

Shawna

Comment: See my answer! Did that work?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `!important` to override existing styles.